# Is it possible to detect unnecessary type guards?

Tags: typescript, static-analysis

I have the following Typescript code:

```
type Nothing = undefined | null;
export const isNothing = <T>(val: T | Nothing): val is Nothing =>
  val === null || typeof val === 'undefined';
```

`isNothing` is a type-guard that basically checks whether or not a value is set or not.

I'd like to detect the following before runtime:

```
const foo:number = 42;
if(isNothing(foo)) { /* ... */ }
```

The case here is that the type-guard is redundant. Since `foo` is explicitly typed, it cannot be `null` or `undefined`.

I've been trying to find answers along the following lines:

- Overloading `isNothing` to return type `never` if `val` is not a union type
- Some linter rule that flags when a parameter to a function that takes a union is not a union (this feels like a sledgehammer approach).
- Some linter rule that explicitly detects unnecessary type-guards

In this case, 'detecting' would either be a compile-time error or a linter notification. Importantly, it would be a pre-runtime detection.

Comment: What should the result of "detecting" be?

Comment: @user2864740 awesome question - I've updated to clarify that I mean "pre-runtime", either by `tslint` or `tsc`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `overloading` so that the type guard return `never`? A type guard must return a boolean. To the second bullet point: Perhaps you mean an intersection type as paramter, then all passed types must fulfill the specified constraints.

Comment: @iY1NQ, so, i was scratching around for avenues to explore. by 'overloading', i meant that, if the function was passed a non-union type, the signature would return `never`, which would lead to an error in my code (which is what i want)... i don't think that avenue will be fruitful

Comment: @iY1NQ as for 'Perhaps you mean an intersection type as parameter', I'm not sure what you're driving at... ultimately this is a type-guard, so it's going to need to take a union, right?

Comment: @Dancrumb I played around a little: A somewhat obscure solution would be to force a runtime check that a parameter is "maybe undefined or null" before the actual guard is invoked: ```function assertMaybeNothing<T extends (Exclude<T, Exclude<T, undefined | null>> extends never ? never : any)>(arg1: T) {
  return true;
}``` and then ```if (assertMaybeNothing(foo) && isNothing(foo)) {}```. The code won't compile because `foo` is never `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Dancrumb I added the code snippet above as answer to your question. Maybe it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in the comments above, there is no such solution that the type guard itself will prevent the code from compiling if a check is redundant. I think with term "type union" you mean in this special case a variable that is not null and not undefined and therefore the `isNothing` type guard check would be redundant.

A solution would be to force the compiler to check that a variable is "maybe null or undefined" before the `isNothing` type guard get invoked:

```
type Nothing = undefined | null;

export const isNothing = <T>(val: T | Nothing): val is Nothing =>
  val === null || typeof val === 'undefined';


let a!: number;
let b!: number | undefined;
let c!: undefined;
let d!: null;

function assertMaybeNothing<T extends (Exclude<T, Exclude<T, undefined | null>> extends never ? never : any)>(arg1: T) {
  return true;
}

assertMaybeNothing(a); // error because is never undefined or null
assertMaybeNothing(b);
assertMaybeNothing(c);
assertMaybeNothing(d);

if (assertMaybeNothing(a) && isNothing(a)) {
  let x = a;// is never
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAFgSwHYHMoF4oFdUAmEAZmhAVAD5Sq4A2dA3AFDMQAeYcATsFAMZxUAZz7Jh8JGkw4APABUAfAAoAbgEM6ALijyqsBCgwBKHRrpRxBqRmyLmUKOexYctBlWqhIcYk80uOADk+ESkqORBLKx0EHzqAIQ6tAC2AEYQ3CyxfGlJNLjpmVQABaEkZATZcQL55eHk1XwE+e5MrMT4-MDIQlDqwsKZwACy6iAZkkboClAcwBCEwlDKAKLs-HS4RAoANFDrm9sQe3iEFREU1G2KinPsC0s0EKrFAPzPr9xQOuqoIMYVOpuOgAIw6eTGKAAbwcUG4cVw3FQUGA3FwEBYAF9WAMhrwxhMIFNpMp1MZGFAAPRUubcbg8KAZfjqXBDSzLCJfM5hSrMPHDQmTQyktIU-mDQXjYU2dDKfjigUE6XEkUYZQEcXMZB+MmS5VEknq8lQABkpo5Rrl5KhsMcOSg7Gw-UYNI5n0yzCxUGYQA)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this:

```
type Nothing = undefined | null;

export function isNothing<T>(val: NonNullable<T>): never
export function isNothing<T>(val: T | Nothing): val is Nothing
export function isNothing<T>(val: T) { return val === null || typeof val === 'undefined'; }
```

Then, I set `strict-boolean-expressions` to `true` in my TSLint configuration.

As a result, my linter now catches whenever a variable of an explicit type that does not contain `null` or `undefined` is passed to this function.